# Comparing different classes in C++ with operator == and !=

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare different classes of objects in C++. 
Everything works well if I remove `section3`. But I'd like to know how to edit the comparative operators `==` and `!=` to make it work without any errors? 
The error that I get is `"no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Fruit' and 'Plant') "`

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Plant
{
public:
    Plant(std::string name) : type_(name)
    { }

    bool operator==(const Plant &that) const
    { return type_ == that.type_; }

    bool operator!=(const Plant &that) const
    { return !operator==(that); }

    void print()
    { std::cout << type_ << std::endl; }

protected:
    std::string type_;
};

class Fruit: public Plant
{
public:
    Fruit(std::string name, std::string taste)
        : Plant(name)
        , taste_(taste)
    { }

    bool operator==(const Fruit& that) const
    {
        return ( (taste_ == that.taste_) && (Plant::operator==(that)) );
    }

    bool operator!=(const Fruit& that) const
    {
        return !operator==(that);
    }

    void print()
    {
        Plant::print();
        std::cout << taste_ << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::string taste_;
};


int main()
{
    Plant a("Maple");
    a.print();
    Plant b("Maple");

    if (a == b)
    {
        std::cout << "a and b are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "a and b are not equal" << std::endl;
    }

    Fruit c("Apple","sweet");
    c.print();
    Fruit d("Apple","sweet");

    if (c == d)
    {
        std::cout << "c and d are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "c and d are not equal" << std::endl;
    }

    if (a == c)
    {
        std::cout << "a and c are equal" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "a and c are not equal" << std::endl;
    }

    /* Section 3 */
    if (c == a)
    { std::cout <<"c and a are equal\n"<< std::endl; }
    else
    { std::cout <<"c and a are not equal\n"<< std::endl; }

    if (a != c)
    { std::cout <<"c and a are not equal\n"<< std::endl; }
    else
    { std::cout <<"c and a are equal\n"<< std::endl; }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks ..

Comment: Operators and inheritance don't play nice. Your Fruit is trying to compare the other object as a Fruit, but Plants aren't necessarily Fruit. This is actually not a simple problem to solve. One way is virtual operators and using RTTI to find out the type of the other object.

Comment: How should these comparisons behave? (in your design). For example, what if someone compares a Fruit with a Carrot?

Comment: If you include in the `Fruit` class: `using Plant::operator==;`, then your comparisons will compile and use `Plant::operator==` to do the comparison

Comment: Doesn't `a != c` compile?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf no

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `a != c` compiles. `c != a` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to either implement comparitor operators to compare Fruit and Plant or downcast the Fruit to a plant in the comparison:

```
bool operator==(const Plant& plant, const Fruit& fruit) { /* test here */ }
bool operator==(const Fruit& fruit, const Plant& plant) { return (plant == fruit); }
```

Or if you have pointers:

```
Fruit* fruit = new Fruit("apple", "sour");
Plant* plant = new Plant("maple"); 
if(*plant == *static_cast<Plant*>(fruit)) {}
```

Comment: How should a Plant and a Fruit compare?

Comment: If it is pointers they can... Plant* fruit = new Fruit("apple", "sour");
If it makes sense is another question. But in that case one can compare pointers

Comment: What I mean is, logically speaking, how should the two compare? I would think a Plant and a Fruit should always compare unequal.

Comment: I agree with you, I don't even think that a fruit is a plant... Since it is a coding question, I gave a code example that is valid. For the practicality of the answer the user should decide.

Comment: Well a Fruit is a plant, surely we can agree on that?

Comment: I think this is off topic but: "a fruit is a part of a flowering plant" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit). Part of a plant, not a plant :P

Comment: @TheBadger Thanks for your comment but I tried it and it still throws errors

Comment: @W.A, what is the error that you get? The pointer constructors above require arguments but apart from that it compiles on my computer (will edit). And I did not show the != operators but you can do that in the same way as the == operators

Comment: @TheBadger " 'Fruit' does not name a type" that's the error. By the way should I replace the existing overloaded == operator with the one suggested by you ?

Comment: There is no need for operator new here, don't do this

Comment: @W.A On what line do you get the error? No, you keep what you have but add the operators that I gave as non member functions (you can add them just above your main() function). The pointers are possibly not what you want, but I showed that it can be used if needed

Comment: @W.A You will get that error if you put the code above any one of the class declarations (`class Fruit ...` or `class Plant ...`). Thus it must be added after both classes are defined, before they are used, thus before the `int main()` should be good enough

Comment: @TheBadger Thank You so much , Fixed its location and I also had some problem with the curly braces. So, I put every statement within a curly braces and it worked perfectly .. Thanks again for your help.. Ive been straggling for 3 days now ..

Answer (score 1):

You can add non-member functions,

```
bool operator==(Fruit const& f, Plant const& p)
{
   return false;
}

bool operator!=(Fruit const& f, Plant const& p)
{
   return !(f == p);
}
```

This will work for one sub-type of `Plant`. This approach is not scalable. If you create more sub-types of `Plant`, you'll need to use a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

It's bit unclear what you're trying to achieve, but apparently it involves **dynamic type checking** where two objects compare equal if they dynamically are of some common base type `X` and are equal according to some criterion specified in that base type.

Finding the common type `X` is in general a thorny problem, because C++ supports multiple inheritance. But if one assumes, for simplicity, **single inheritance**, that is, the case where each class has at most one base class, then one can let one of the objects that are involved in a comparison, walk up the **base class chain** and use e.g. `dynamic_cast` to check if the other object is of this type, e.g. like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>      // std::move

using Byte_string = std::string;

class Base
{
private:
    Byte_string s_;

protected:
    virtual
    auto equals( Base const& other ) const
        -> bool
    { return s_ == other.s_; }

public:
    friend
    auto operator==( Base const& a, Base const& b )
        -> bool
    { return a.equals( b ); }

    explicit Base( Byte_string s )
        : s_( move( s ) )
    {}
};

class Derived
    : public Base
{
private:
    Byte_string t_;

protected:
    auto equals( Base const& other ) const
        -> bool override
    {
        if( auto p_other = dynamic_cast<Derived const*>( &other ) )
        {
            return Base::equals( other ) and t_ == p_other->t_;
        }
        return Base::equals( other );
    }

public:
    Derived( Byte_string s, Byte_string t )
        : Base( move( s ) )
        , t_( move( t ) )
    {}
};

class Most_derived
    : public Derived
{
private:
    int u_;

protected:
    auto equals( Base const& other ) const
        -> bool override
    {
        if( auto p_other = dynamic_cast<Most_derived const*>( &other ) )
        {
            return Derived::equals( other ) and u_ == p_other->u_;
        }
        return Derived::equals( other );
    }

    Most_derived( Byte_string s, Byte_string t, int u )
        : Derived( move( s ), move( t ) )
        , u_( u )
    {}

};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Base a( "Maple" );
    Base b( "Maple" );
    cout << "a and b are " << (a == b? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";

    Derived c( "Apple", "sweet" );
    Derived d( "Apple", "sweet" );
    cout << "c and d are " << (c == d? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";

    cout << "a and c are " << (a == c? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";
    cout << "c and a are " << (c == a? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";

    Base& x = d;
    cout << "x and c are " << (x == c? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";
    cout << "c and x are " << (c == x? "" : "not ") << "equal.\n";

}
```